# Getting Doctrine\Collection from select form element in zend framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to implement https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac in my module. At the moment I'm stuck, because I get following exception:

> Argument 1 passed to User\Entity\User::setRoles() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection, array given ...

Line, that causes the error in UserManager class: `$user->setRoles($data['role']);`

So it's clear, that setter in the entity is wrong or form element of type select which returns the `$data['role']` element.

Code of setter:

```
public function setRoles(Collection $roles)
{
    $this->roles->clear();
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $this->roles[] = $role;
    }
}
```

Code of select element in UserForm:

```
$this->add([            
        'type'  => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
        'name' => 'role',
        'attributes' => [
            'multiple' => true,
        ],
        'options' => [
            'object_manager' => $this->entityManager,
            'target_class' => 'User\Entity\Role',
            'label' => 'Role',
            'value_options' => $roles,
            'disable_inarray_validator' => true, //TODO: create validator
            'required' => true,
        ],
    ]);
```

**So how cane I make select element return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection?**

I tried to use ArrayCollection from Doctrine namespace, but it didn't work. Do I have to make separate class, that implements Collection interface and use it with select element? Or maybe there is some more conveniant ways to achieve this?

I also tried with removed @var, @param annotations and types in the Entity, but in this case I've got following message:

> Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array" for association field "User\Entity\User#$roles", got "string" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. The setter in User entity is correct I just had to make small helper function, that will convert array from select input into array of Role objects:

```
private function getRolesFromArray($array){
    $roles = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Role::class)
            ->findBy(['id'=> $array]);
    return new ArrayCollection($roles);
}
```

So ArrayCollection works!
Also there is properly made select field in Form object:

```
$this->add([            
        'type'  => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
        'name' => 'role',
        'attributes' => [
            'multiple' => true,
        ],
        'options' => [
            'object_manager' => $this->entityManager,
            'target_class' => 'User\Entity\Role',
            'label' => 'Role',
            'required' => true,
        ],
    ]);
```